# Java Generic hierarchy definition

Tags: java, generics

Trying to create a generic expression evaluator generalized on the type of params passed in for evaluation

```
public interface Expression<T> {
   Boolean evaluate(LinkedHashMap<String, T> params) throws Exception
}

public class JavaScriptExpression implements Expression<Object> {
  ...
}
```

I have a Condition type that hosts this expression and evaluates it and returns it true

```
public class Condition<T extends Expression> {

    private T expression;

    public Optional<Step> execute(LinkedHashMap<String, R> variableMapping) {

    }  
}
```

`R` in the above `execute(LinkedHashMap<String, R>)` is based on the Expression type passed in as type `T`, if JavaScriptExpression, R is Object etc.,

How this type information can be encoded in the type definition with generics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add `R` as a type parameter to `Condition`.

```
public class Condition<T extends Expression<R>, R> {
```

Comment: I can assume there is no way I can extract R from T? just out of curiosity how does scala fair in this scenario, since it sells it type system very high

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar No, I don't think so. You can use the "diamond operator" (`new Condition<>()`) or a method to make the call site smaller. I imagine Scala does much better (but pays a heavy price for it).